# Why does John/Jane in the movie Predestination blame the stranger for ruining his/her life?

Tags: predestination

John/Jane blames the stranger for ruining her life and would kill him in a heartbeat if possible.

Why does she blame him?

Is it for having sex with her?

That fling did require consent of both of them, so if there is anyone to blame, its both of them.

Or is it because the stranger got her pregnant?

Again, its mentioned she excelled in academics so I assume she'd have the basic knowledge of biology to understand one can become pregnant after having sex without protection, so if there is anyone to blame, its both of them.

Or is it because the stranger left her?

Can she not think of a scenario e.g. he got hit by a car and died?

Lets say she thinks he left her.
How is that life ruining? She liked someone, had sex, and he left. How did the leaving ruin her life?

Comment: The original short story, Heinlein's [All You Zombies...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies) was written in 1958. The movie Predestination carries many of the [original story's social background](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SocietyMarchesOn) into the present day, [with some jarring effects.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ValuesDissonance)

Comment: In the story, her lover comes back and steals her baby.

Comment: @sueelleker
But she does not know that does she?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jane feels that the "city slicker" she encountered ruined her life. In addition to tricking her into having sex, he managed to get her pregnant (despite her birth-control) which resulted in her

- Losing her job (as well as her accomodation)
- Being ejected from the W.E.N.C.H.E.S program
- Suffering so much internal damage that the doctors felt that it was appropriate to reassign her gender.

On top of all of that, she strongly suspects that he was the one that stole her baby from the hospital.

> “Then I met this city slicker with his hundred–dollar bills.” He scowled. “The no–good actually did have a wad of hundred–dollar bills. He showed me one night, told me to help myself.
>
> “But I didn’t. I liked him. He was the first man I ever met who was nice to me without trying games with me. **I quit night school to see him oftener.** It was the happiest time of my life.
>
> “Then one night in the park the games began.”
>
> He stopped. I said, “And then?”
>
> **“And then nothing! I never saw him again. He walked me home and told me he loved me—and kissed me good—night and never came back.” He looked grim. “If I could find him, I’d kill him!”**
>
> <sub><sup>[All you zombies...](http://emilkirkegaard.dk/en/wp-content/uploads/Robert-A.-Heinlein-All-You-Zombies.pdf)</sup></sub>

and

> “Just a man, with a face–shaped face, like yours or mine.” He frowned. **“I think it was the baby’s father.** The nurse swore it was an older man but he probably used makeup. Who else would swipe my baby? Childless women pull such stunts—but whoever heard of a man doing it?”